# getting the changed lines jtextarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am doing a text editor which needs custom validation.  Since, the content is very large i thought of validating only the lines which are changed or added. The validation errors are shown by the line numbers, like "Line: 10 cannot exceed 15 chars"

1. For single lines, every time the user changes iam validating the current line, keeping the row number as reference. - solved
2. The user can copy text and paste - multiple lines.  for this, thought of getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd.  Is there a way of getting the row numbers from getSelectionStart and getSelectionEnd, so i can get starting row and ending row?

After some exprements i thought selecting the lines which are visible will solve my above statated No. 2 problem.

Rectangle would solve in getting the x, y cordinates of viewable region and wrote the code, i think i am almost finished.  But, i am not getting the end row number correctly,

```
      [code]
    //editor is jtextarea
      Rectangle r = editor.getVisibleRect();
      Point top = new Point(r.x, r.y);
      Point bottom = new Point(r.x, r.y + r.height);
      int startRow = editor.viewToModel(top); /* this is working. it shows 0 at           initial, then after the line reaches the end and when the scrollbar gets displayed, it shows the numbers correctly, 1,2,3...*/
     int endRow = editor.viewToModel(bottom); /* this is not working, when we type, it is taking column numbers */
     editorLineNo.setText(" START ROW " + startRow + " END ROW" + endRow);
     [/code]

     What is needed is, start row number and end row number from the viewable area  of jtextarea
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it was very useful, now i thought, to select only the code which are visible.  For this, i used Rectangle to get the viewable portion.  The only part remaing is converting the rectangle y cordinate to row, here is the code, http://pastebin.com/AvCWqNzj

Comment: Thanks, camickr. I am almost there only the end row number is not getting corrctly, pastebin.com/UgKCHgcx – shiva0101 m

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way of getting the row numbers ...

```
Element root = textArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
int row = root.getElementIndex( selectionStart ) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it was very useful, now i thought, to select only the code which are visible. For this, i used Rectangle to get the viewable portion. The only part remaing is converting the rectangle y cordinate to row, here is the code, [link]http://pastebin.com/vU1KZCwK

Comment: You can use the `viewToModel(...)` method to get and offset into the Document and then use the code above to get the row.

Comment: Thanks, camickr.  I am almost there only the end row number is not getting corrctly, http://pastebin.com/UgKCHgcx

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating your problem with your original question.

Answer (score 3):

[Utilities.getRowStart() / getRowEnd()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html#getRowStart%28javax.swing.text.JTextComponent,%20int%29) passing the offsets.

Comment: This doesn't give the "row number".

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it was very useful, now i thought, to select only the code which are visible. For this, i used Rectangle to get the viewable portion. The only part remaing is converting the rectangle y cordinate to row, here is the code, [link]http://pastebin.com/vU1KZCwK

Comment: viewToModel() pass the x, y and get position in the document.